# I have a dynamic spinner, if i clicked the item in the spinner, i want to linked to another layout

Tags: android, android-spinner

Here is the code:
Help me guys, i'm just new here. thank you so much! i'm having a hard time searching for        the solutions.. Thank you so much, it is well appreciated.
It should be link to the same xml layout.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    /* when spinner item is clicked it should linked to another layout.. it should link in add_student layout

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                 String str = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();

                             //here print selected value...
                 System.out.println("String is :: " + str);

                             //And StartActivity here...

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StudentActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
     */

}


}
```

Comment: Tell your problem here. What you need??

Comment: go to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948487/android-how-to-get-value-from-spinner-and-based-on-value-to-redirect-to-anothe/19948697#19948697) page.
it may help you..

Comment: When i clicked the item in the spinner, i want it to go to another xml. Thank you..

Comment: @TarunDroid When i clicked the item in the spinner, i want it to go to another xml. Thank you..

Comment: @PiyushGupta When i clicked the item in the spinner, i want it to go to another xml. Thank you..

Comment: @NaveedAli thanks for the link.. but i didn't declare any string array in the resources.. the user will input the data

Comment: @user3349819 means in new activity?

Comment: @PiyushGupta how about in new activity?

Comment: Means go to from one screen to another.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes sir, that's what i want to know..

Comment: @PiyushGupta how will i do that? the user will input the data that will be save in the spinner. and when the user clicked the item in it, it will go to the new activity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add custom layout to Spinner than you should use this..

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivityName.this, R.layout.yourcusomlayout, urarraylistValue);
  spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And if you want to navigate from one activity to another use this on item click of Spinner

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
                String str = spinner.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StudentActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("myvalue" , str);
                startActivity(intent);

        }


        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Now in your StudentActivity retrieve your data on oncreate() method as follows.

```
    Intent n = getIntent();

    String myData = n.getStringExtra("myvalue");
```

Now you can see your value here from selected spinner to which you can set in TextView or print in Log.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.. hmm where should i assign the "myData" thanks!

Comment: you can assign it to TextView , EditText or Button else print in log.

Comment: Thank you! @PiyushGupta what is the function of "myData"?

Comment: It is your selected spinner item value.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
The following will give you the selected item position

```
spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

The following is the listener:

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
              //Put if else or switch case here to start an appropriate intent 


        }
```

From the [Official Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition)

Answer (score 0):

What you want? You add other layout or other activity.

If you add layout try below code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.yourlayout, yourvalues);
spinner.setAdapter(ad);
```